# Backbone - NestedModels - Nested sets not firing "change"

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, nested, backbone-views

I am using this [Backbone nested plugin](https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested).
I wrote my binding like this :

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(params) {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.rerender, this));
    }
```

The model I passed to the view is declared like this, outside of the view in global scope :

```
newModel = new Backbone.NestedModel(jsonData);
```

When i write **newModel.set("prop", "value")** it triggers a change and fires rerender

But when I write **newModel.set("prop.prop", "value")** it doesn't trigger "change" **if prop.prop already existed**. That means that a value change isn't detected.

**But a new value is detected**: newModel.set("newProp.newProp", "value") triggers a change

*Nested gets DO WORK*.

I can do `newModel.get("prop.prop")` it returns the value

Now, if i listen to a **specific property** it does work :

```
this.model.bind('change:prop.prop', _.bind(this.rerender, this));
} //fires rerender
```

According to the plugin docs, listening to "change" should fire a change in any case :

// this will fire when 'name.middle.initial' is set or changed

```
user.bind('change', function(model, newVal){ ... });
```

but it doesn't. What did I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

what about if you try by delegating the event to the view by using [listen to](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)?

points out: 
   - You can pass the context as the param 4th so you don't need to bind the callback function which will make your code a bit slower due to an unnecessary function call.

eg

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(params) {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.rerender, this);
     }
```

Hope this solution help you.

Cheers

Comment: This still doesn't work.
The behavior is exactly the same, but I have found some more details (gonna edit the question)